# Substitution Control and Cache Location

Tags: asp.net, caching, outputcache

If I use Substitution control in asp.net page, and also add the following directive to the page:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="7200" VaryByParam="None" Location="Any" %>
```

Would the location attribute be ignored, since using Substitution control on a page makes the page cacheable only on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will be ignored. Substition.Render calls, through RenderMarkup, HttpResponse.WriteSubstitution that calls HttpCachePolicy.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Server).